# Mod Rewrite / Rewrite to Sub Directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been trying to figure out mod_rewrite for days and I was wondering if you guys have any ideas

My primary domain is siteX.com, which maps to 'public_html' directory.

Recently, I added another domain, called siteY.com, and i marked 'public_html/siteY/public_html' as its root directory.

Now I'm trying to change my root directory for siteX, by mapping it to' public_html/siteX/public_html', but I when I implement mod_rewrite, it lets the users see the url to be 'http://www.siteX.com/siteX/public_html'. I need my primarly domain to map automatically to the correct directory with the using see only 'http://www.siteX.com'.

To better illustrate the directories im referring to.

```
public_html (siteX, my primary domain marks this as root directory)
    - .htaccess file
    - siteX
        -public_html (siteX i want my primarily domain to mark this as root directory)
    - siteY
        -public_html ( siteY.com marks this as root directory)
```

I hope I made the problem clear. Thank you.

This is currently the rewrite rule I am using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?siteX.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.siteX.com/siteX/public_html/index.php
```

For my hosting company, I believe mod_rewrite is the only way to go

Comment: Have you tried something like `RewriteRule ^siteX/(.*) /siteX/public_html/$1` in theory that should rewrite `http://www.siteX.com/siteX/public_html/index.php` to `http://www.siteX.com/siteX/index.php`

Answer (score 1):

When you have `http://www.siteX.com` as part of the target in a `RewriteRule`, it automatically *redirects the browser*. It's like having the `[R]` flag. I think you want something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?siteX.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/siteX
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /siteX/public_html/$1 [L]
```

To internally rewrite all requests for the host `siteX.com` to the `/siteX/public_html/` directory.